# Getting an image from the database using path images on the client side

Tags: reactjs, node.js, multer

I used multer to download the image and save the path of the image to the database, and then how can I get the image from the client and show it on the screen?

```
import multer from 'multer';

const storageConfig = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
         cb(null, './images')
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +  file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage: storageConfig});

 let path = '';

app.post('/upload',upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    if(req.file) {
        console.log(req.file);
        path = req.file.path;
        res.send('hi')
        return;
    }
    res.send('bye')
})
```

after I received the file path I saved it in the database, but I don’t know how to use it later to show this picture on the screen

Comment: Save the response in a state and then use img tag to show the image by putting image state in src.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code mention, you can show the image in react as below.

```
<img src={`${backend_url}/${path_you_get_from_database}`} />
```

In your case backend_url is http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

After saving the path of the file to the database, you need to implement a route to fetch the image url. Then you can simply use it in your client application. Here I'm expecting you are only fetching a single image using the id. If you want to fetch all the urls stored in db, kindly make necessary changes to this code.

Eg:

Server.js

```
app.get('/image/:id', async (req, res) => {
  //Assuming you have a db connection pool and you are using postgres
  const client = await pool.connect();
  const { id } = req.params;
  const query = 'SELECT url from imag_collection WHERE id = $1';
  const result = await client.query(query, [id]);
  if (!result.rowCount) {
    // Your error handling logic
    // or simply
    res.status(404).json({ message: 'No image found using the given id' });
  }
  res.status(200).json({url: result.rows[0].url});
});
```

Client (ReactJS)

```
// Collect id from user

const result = await fetch(`${serverUrl}/image/${id}`);
    
if(!result.ok) {
  // Handle the error here
}
    
<img src={`${result.url}`} />
```